# Swift handle favorite and unfavorite button based on JSON value

Tags: ios, json, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to implement favorite and unfavorite functionality into my cell. Here, Initially I am showing in collection view cell button icon `favorite (gray)`, its mean unfavorite but after clicked the button it will show green, its mean favorite. From `JSON` I am getting response which cells are already favorite and others unfavorite icon. Its working fine but when I click `JSON` favorite enabled green button it’s not changing gray by single click, its working fine double click but every click I am calling `JSON` so `3rd` click it will be add again favorite.

Here, below my code -

```
var checked = false

 @IBAction func favoritesTapped(_ sender: Any) {

            if checked {
                favbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "item_grayfav.png"), for: .normal)
                checked = false
                delegate?.unfavoriteButtonPressed(cell: self)

            } else {
                favbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "item_greenfav.png"), for: .normal)
                checked = true
                delegate?.favoriteButtonPressed(cell: self)
            }
}
```

Above code I am using for button click to change image and also initially I fixed gray `checked = false`

Into collection view cell at item

```
 if indexPath.row < cfavoritesIDData.count {

            if let i = cfavoritesIDData[indexPath.item] {
                cell.favbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "item_greenfav.png"), for: .normal)
            }
            else {
                print("id is nil")
                cell.favbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "item_grayfav.png"), for: .normal)
            }
}
```

**Issues**: If I click JSON enabled green button (favorite), its calling to unfavorite well but button icon not changing green after 3’rd click only its changing gray.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your cell model in your `View Controller`, the cell should not have a `checked` boolean, when you are configuring your cell in `cellForRow:` you should tell it there wether it is checked or not.

When pressing the button you should have a `delegate` callback or `closure` to tell the  `View Controller` that the cell at `IndexPath` 'x' has pressed its favourite button and check the model as to wether or not the reaction would be checked or not, then reconfigure the cell again.

Comment: why would I provide code, you need to understand the concept and the code will write itself...

Comment: I can't able to understand that is the reason I am asking dude @SeanLintern88

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UIButton's selected property instead of checked variable:

```
if indexPath.row < favoritesIDData.count {

    if let i = cfavoritesIDData[indexPath.item] {
        cell.favbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "item_greenfav.png"), for: .normal)
        cell.favbutton.setSelected = true
    }
    else {
        print("id is nil")
        cell.favbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "item_grayfav.png"), for: .normal)
        cell.favbutton.setSelected = false
    }
}




@IBAction func favoritesTapped(_ UIButton: favButton) {

    if favButton.isSelected {
        favbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "item_grayfav.png"), for: .normal)
        checked = false
        delegate?.unfavoriteButtonPressed(cell: self)

    } else {
        favbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "item_greenfav.png"), for: .normal)
        checked = true
        delegate?.favoriteButtonPressed(cell: self)
    }
}
```

Note: Don't copy paste change according to correct syntax.

Comment: Sure I will try and let you know. thank you. Btw Value of type 'UIButton' has no member 'setSelected' I am getting error. @guru

Comment: What is the issue

Comment: change the selection state again in favoriteButtonPressed or reload the collection.